# Applying window constraint in DTW

Tags: r

I use dtw package in r.

I am comparing the results of the simulation against those of experiment results.
I need to adjust the time shift (neither the scale in x-axis nor in y-axis), because the timing of events can be a little bit different.

I use the following function.

```
alignment<-dtw(exp, sim, keep=TRUE, 
           window.type='sakoechiba', 
           window.size=1);
```

Even though I set the window.size=1, the points that are quite far to each other are matched together.

How can I fix this issue? thanks,

Comment: Can you make your [example reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?